# NoHandlerError Paperclip on ruby on rails 3.2.1

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I am trying to make available to upload a multiple pictures with paperclip. I am following this tutorial: http://www.emersonlackey.com/article/paperclip-with-rails-3

Unfortunately I have error:

```
No handler found for "apple_mac-1280x800.jpg"
```

**Asset.rb**

```
class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  has_attached_file :asset, :styles => { :small => "100x100", :original => '800x600>'}
end
```

**Post.rb**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assets
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :assets, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

Posts_controller.rb

```
def new
    @post = Post.new
    5.times { @post.assets.build }

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @post }
    end
end

def edit
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  5.times { @post.assets.build }
end
```

**@Post form**

```
<% create_url = {:url=>{:action=>"create"}} if @post.new_record? %>
    <% form_for @post, :html => {:multipart => true}  do |t| %>
      <p>
        <%= t.label :title, 'Virsraksts:' %>
        <%= t.text_field :title %>
      </p>
      <p>
        <%= t.label :content, 'Teksts:' %>
        <%= t.text_area :content, :class => "mceEditor"%>
      </p>

      <%= t.fields_for :assets do |asset_fields| %>
         <% if asset_fields.object.new_record? %>
            <p>
                <%= asset_fields.file_field :asset %>
            </p>
         <% end %>
      <% end %>


      <%= t.submit %>
    <% end %>
<%end%>
```

**Problem solved** by changing

```
<%= t.fields_for :assets do |asset_fields| %>
```

to

```
<%= f.fields_for :assets do |asset_fields| %>
```

But could someone explain why?

Comment: what is `f`? you don't mention that variable anywhere in your source code